# Access to html tags in .Net Core Web application (.NET 5)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I have written a .NET Core Web Application using .NET 5, and I want to access HTML tags and modify them in .cs back code.

I want this tag in .cshtml.cs file

```
<div id="log_wrapper" name="log_wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: ASP.NET 5 has *multiple* stacks but *none* of the uses `runat="server"`. That was only used in the ancient WebForms stack that was replaced by MVC a decade ago.  WebForms wasn't migrated to .NET Core nor are there any plans to do so

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how can I access them in .net 5?

Comment: What are you trying to do? ASP.NET MVC is *completely* different from WebForms, and so are the newer Razor Pages. WebForms didn't access the HTML tags either, it only tried to give that impression. In MVC and later a Controller handles the request and generates a ViewModel. A View then uses it to generate the final HTML. You can use the ViewModel data in the view either through code or through data binding

Comment: You should probably check [Choose an ASP.NET Core web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/choose-web-ui?view=aspnetcore-5.0), [Tutorial: Create a Razor Pages web app with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or  [Get started with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: We usually change the html code in .cshtml file ,why you want to change it in .cs file?